# Need help architecting the AWS infrastructure for Apache webserver running in EKS serving static html content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, eksctl

My requirement is I need to deploy a docker container built on Apache to EKS. This container will hold some static html, js and css files. I need to expose out these files through a URL to the client. What AWS services do I need to setup. I don't have experience but if high level direction is provided, I can research and put something together. Thanks.

Have not tried anything yet. Still looking for guidance.

Comment: Hosting Static files on EKS is an overkill. Why not use S3 for example?

Comment: This is the requirement I have to work with.